# Ansible jinja2 compare strings non case sensitive

Tags: string, ansible, comparison, jinja2, json-query

I have following complex dictionary (this is just a sample). And I'm trying to grab a list of all ids which belong to server1. Name of the server1 is in mixed cases.

I tried jinja2 filters like `match`, `search`, `equalto` but none of them returns expected result. Also tried JSON query but still missing how to lower or upper case all for compare to work.

```yaml
    ---
    - name: TEST
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: no
    
      vars:
        datacenters: {
          cabinets: {
            servers: [
              {
                name: Server1,
                id: 1
              },
              {
                name: SERVER1,
                id: 2
              },
              {
                name: Server2,
                id: 3
              },
              {
                name: server1,
                id: 4
              },
             ]
          }
        }
    
      tasks:
        - name: get ids for Server 1 
          set_fact:
            ids: "{{ datacenters.cabinets.servers
              | selectattr('name','match','Server1')
              | map(attribute='id')
              | list }}"
    
        - debug:
              var: ids
    
        - debug: msg="{{ datacenters | json_query(\"cabinets.servers[?name == 'Server1'].id\") }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with when and `lower` filter of ansible. The below playbook works for me.

**Playbook:**

```
- name: Demo of restore plan
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    datacenters: {
        cabinets: {
          servers: [
            {
              name: Server1,
              id: 1
            },
            {
              name: SERVER1,
              id: 2
            },
            {
              name: Server2,
              id: 3
            },
            {
              name: server1,
              id: 4
            },
          ]
        }
      }
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ datacenters.cabinets.servers }}"
      when: item.name|lower == "server1"
```

**Output:**

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [Demo of restore plan] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'Server1', 'id': 1}) => {
    "msg": "Server1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'SERVER1', 'id': 2}) => {
    "msg": "SERVER1"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'Server2', 'id': 3})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'server1', 'id': 4}) => {
    "msg": "server1"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Ansible lists only the server1 line and ignores the server2

Hope so this helps

Comment: thats correct answer. do you know if there is a way to achieve the same without having using the loop but rather jinja2 syntax ?